# Android- Splitting a string into multiple strings

Tags: java, android, string, split

As the title states. Ok, so, for example, I wanted to make a Pig Latin converter. So, the User types something in the text box(ir whatever it's called). Then, I convert that to a string. Now, I need to remove the first letter of the word to the end, and then add "ay". But, if the string is a sentence, it'll just move the first letter of the first word to the last letter of the last word. I need it to do that for each word within the string. So I need a way to split the string per word, and then for each word, do the method in which converts it into pig Latin, with the exception of vowels. So, all I reallly need is to split up each word and reference it in a simple way somehow. I would probably have to use a for loop. I'm just not sure how. I think I can do the rest. It's just that one part. If anybody wants to help me out with the exceptions of vowels, that'll be nice to.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.split(" ")` to split it into words, and then do what you need to do on the individual words.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" ")));
ArrayList<String> convertedWords = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String word : words) {
    convertedWords.add(convertToPigLatin(word));
}
```